# How To get value of textbox placed in Custom user control using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have one Asp.net page. Where I have used one user control in that page. Custom control contains one listbox and one textbox.

When Click on Button on page I want to display textbox value using jquery. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If `TextBox` don't have attribute `ClientIDMode = "static"`, then try the following.

```
$("[id$='textbox_id']").val()
```

If you set `ClientIDMode = "static"` attribute, then you can use the following

```
$("#textbox_id").val()
```

This will give you the `TextBox` text.

Comment: I have used multiple instance of the user control in the same page

Comment: @Urvashi Both will give you the first occurrence of the `TextBox`. But is it necessary to use same usercontrol multiple times?

Comment: Yes its necessary. So how can I get the value of textbox?

Comment: @Urvashi The above code will give you the value of first occurrence of the `TextBox`. If you want a specific `TextBox`, then its depends on your `html` structure.